# NodeJS: Passing a variable into a different variable's name

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I create a function that accepts a value and creates a watchfile listener based on that value received?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
function createListener(id) {
  var listener(id here) = fs.watchFile(file, function () {
  });
});
```

How could I place the `id` given to function `createListener();` into the listener's assigned variable?

Example: `createListener('5');` would create `var listener5 = fs.watchFile();`

`createListener('23');` would create `var listener23 = fs.watchFile();`

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're after? Even if you could create it, the variable would be local to the function. Would an object with the key set to the id not suffice? Then you can do `watching = {}; watching[id] = fs.watchFile(); var listener = watching[id];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` to create dynamic variable names

but it is **bad part** of **JavaScript** and I **strongly recommend not to use** `eval` at all.

---

I recommend you to use either **array or JSON** objects to store multiple functions.

**Array**

```
var functions = [];
functions.push = function () { ... };

// functions = [ function () { ... } ];
```

**JSON**

```
var functions = {};
functions["one"] = function () { ... };

// functions = { one: function () { ... } };
```